# How combine these two with each other?(OS python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, operating-system

I made this 2 pack of codes but I do not know how I can put my password on my folder with os library. it will be nice if somebody can help me

```
import random

small = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
capital = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
numbers = "123456789"
symbol = "[] { } () : ; @ $ &"
password = small + capital + numbers + symbol
lenght = 15
password = "".join(random.sample(password , lenght))
print(password)
```

```
import os

path = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\Chris\\Python"
os.chdir(path)
files = "new file"
for i in range (1,11):
    files = "new file" + str(i)
    os.makedirs(files)
```

Comment: Do you want to generate a list of files with hash names? Are you trying to password protect them? Needs a little more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file using the `open()` function, like this:
`f = open('filename.txt', 'w')`

Then use the `write()` method to write what you need inside your file:
`f.write('mycontent')`

Finally, don't forget to close the file with the `close()` method:
`f.close()`

This can also be achieved with the following syntax:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write('mycontent') # you don't need to use f.close()
```